# Divide column into many columns SQL based on id and sort

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmOIv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntnyy.png)

I want to create a query (works as a view) to get the values of specific columns and merge them into one column.

My goal is to divide view into columns monday - friday by id_day (1-monday, 2-tuesday,...) and sort them by id_time putting in appropriate row.

I'd like to create something like timetable so lessons don't have to start everyday from the same hour (it needs to be empty cell when appropriate lesson doesn't exist). Time column will be taken from Time table.

How to do this? I'm using MS Access file as my database.

EDIT: I added examples of view and goal. Also I found this would help me but I have no idea how to put data in appropriate rows.
I have to have a single timetable as one query becasue I will display it in DataGrid(WPF)

SELECT
(
case id_day='1' then "subject+class+teacher" AS Monday
... till id_day='5'
)
FROM timetable_class WHERE id_class=

Comment: Looks like a CROSSTAB query might be what you need. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html You should post actual data (as table in post, not an image). Provide example raw data and desired output as well as attempted query SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

To get the blank rows in the timetable, you may need to create a table (or query) that has a list of all the possible timeslots first.

Probably also help you to understand if you create a table with the day names and ID's to match your table. (you can use a function to get this, but when you are starting out it may be easier this way.

Add those two tables to your query so that all the data you need to see in the final product is displayed correctly in each record.

then create a crosstab, as per June7's suggestion and you should have it!

Comment: I have tables(id, header): class, room, teacher, day, time,subject.

You mean timeslot table based on id_time and id_day?  Look to my EDIT, something like this?

Comment: To do a crosstab, you need to have ALL the data in the query first.  so you need to add stuff so that you have columns showing the day-name and the time-of-day.  
I believe that the time-of-day table will also need to have entries for all the possible timeslots in the day so that blank ones have a spot.  
So your query before you make a crosstab will have lots of blank spots in the what-classes-are-on-when columns.  
you probably don't need the ID's of the days, names, timeslots and classes.